# pamr: How can I read my txt-file without parm.from.excel?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm just getting started using R. I wanted to use `pamr` , but I am not able to read my data. I tried using something like

```
 my.data <- pamr.from.excel("mydata.txt", 13, sample.labels=TRUE)
```

There was an error that said, that it couldn't find the function "pamr.from.Excel". While reading the Reference Manual, I figured out, that this function doesn't exist in the newest Version of `pamr`. How can I read my data?

I need something like this: "A list with components: x- an expression genes in the rows, samples in the columns), and y- a vector of the class labels for each sample. Optionalcomponents-genenames,avectorofgenenames,andgeneid-avector of gene identiﬁers." (see: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pamr/pamr.pdf)

I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear this function has disappeared from the package after version 1.54.

What you could do is a) install an older version of the package from i.e. GitHub using i.e. `remotes` package (will require building, so you'll need to have the appropriate toolchain), b) use the last known version of the function (i.e. copy/pasting it into your own project, code is [here](https://github.com/cran/pamr/blob/ba4b6a0053967da71e12756592e8bff39274cef4/R/pamr.from.excel.R)) or c) see the before linked function and import the data by hand, emulating the returned object (code from the aforementioned link).

```
return(list(x = x, y = y, genenames = genenames, geneid = geneid, 
            samplelabels = samplelabels, batchlabels = batchlabels))
```